# What is the creative aspect of creative writing?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing, technique

Is 'creative writing' simply a synonym for 'fiction'?

Comment: May I point out that the title of your question does not fit very well to the body of it? Please consider to reconcile the two, and clarify your question(s) on the way. As it is, I pretty much had to guess at the underlying theme of your question and piece together my own version of it. If I got it wrong, that's a perfect example of how different people think differently, see my answer to the question I took from your text. ;-)

Comment: Wow, it's hard to stay polite with an answer like that ... As a general rule, I don't ignore stuff that I don't understand. My gut told me there was something interesting in the question, that I could maybe add a piece of my personal understanding to. However, because there was a slight discrepancy in the way you asked your question, in my opinion at leas, I asked you to clarify it.

Comment: This is a bit hard to answer... If everyone was on the same level of skill where they understood the dynamics and flow of words and writing, then sure there is no "right" way...It would just be their style that differs.  However, comparing joe smith to Tolkien is like comparing your kid brother  to Derek Jeter and when the kid asks how he can perfect his swing you say, everyone's swing has a their own style there is no "right way".  While everyone's swing is generally unique at the pro level, they have also mastered the basic foundations of a swing which your kid brother has not.

Comment: There is a right way to hold the bat, right way to grip the bat, choke up on the bat, which arm to swing with and which one guides the bat.  Basic founding principles that many people at a more advanced level tend to forget at one point they also struggled with and deem it trivial because they care about the artistic style and not the basic foundation.

Comment: That's one drastic way of editing your question :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think any writing that practises writing as a craft is considered creative writing. An idea, technique, or style doesn’t have to have been born out of a void in order to be creative. As you say, 99% of the time it’s how you employ those techniques that already exist, rather than inventing something entirely new. I think you answered your own question and I agree with you. But I disagree that you’re alone or even in a minority for thinking this.

I don’t think many on here are asking for the ONE TRUE WAY to write. I read those “How do you…?” questions more like “How COULD this be done?” rather than “How SHOULD this be done?” In the former case, answering with “whichever way pleases you” is not helpful, because they are stuck at the idea-generating phase, not the “which of my ideas is better” phase. I certainly don’t think it’s uncreative to need a little push sometimes when it comes to creating ideas.

However a “how could this be done?” question can easily fall into the “what-to-write” category, but you can rectify this by asking for examples of where this has been done before, or well-known methods to solve the problem. Then the question becomes more like “How is this usually done?” or “How do you do this?”

There are many ways to write well, not one strict set of rules. Even if there were, that doesn’t mean that any old Joe could follow them and churn out bestseller after bestseller. For example, maths has universal rules, but some people still can’t do maths. Practice helps. Research helps. Asking for advice helps. As far as I understand it, that’s the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 3):

Question 1:

No, the "creative writing" is not a synonym for "fiction". Any documentary piece of work, such as someone's biography, or the account of the events, which happened aboard Titanic on the night of the crash, or the circumstances surrounding the falling of the Tungus meteorite in 1908, falls under the "creative writing" category by default, and while a section of the technical manual, dealing with troubleshooting of the piece of some farming equipment, probably does not belong there, a blog post, dedicated to a variety of methods of sharpening your katana, most likely does.

That is my (opinion-laden) answer to the first question. Without descending into a rant, why the opinion-based questions and answers are frowned upon on this site, I will still try to answer (or expose everyone willing to suffer to my opinion on the matter, while *upvoting the question*, because I believe that it is relevant to many people and the answers to it, however opinionated they might appear, should shed some light on the subject and be actually of use to more than one person).

**(everything below refers to the deleted parts of the initial post)**

Question 2:

> ...it seems the majority of aspiring writers believe there is a perfect way write a story with a perfect arc using perfect language etc, and learning this perfect way will lead to publication and success...

Sadly, yes, and the number (percentage?) of people, who are stuck in that corner is nothing short of horrifying. This site is not an exception.

Some members even openly state that (loose quote): *I intend to learn all I can about rules of writing before starting any serious piece of work, and this is why I am here*, which to me is an equivalent to a statement, say, *I am going to study and perfect my knowledge of musical theory before even touching an instrument of any kind*.

The saddest part is that those people believe that to be the only way to a creative (and, *sigh*, commercial) success.

It is not, and you are absolutely and entirely right when you answer the question *"how do you ..."* with *"whichever way pleases you"*, because the only rules a writer should follow (and I stress *should* vs. *must*) are the rules of grammar and, maybe, *common sense*—the latter, frankly, should be applied to any activity, creative, or not.

> I have a million questions about the dynamics and styles of exposition . . . what makes one version of a story better than another? ... why I never hear writers discussing these things?

The questions of that type are rear here, unfortunately (for all of us), but it could be explained: it is near impossible to ask such question without requesting a critique on a certain excerpt of your writing, and this is not a critique site.

And don't even get me started on the critique sites.

Question 3:

In your particular case, the samples you present can clearly be labeled "tell" (1) and "show" (2), and there is no one in the world to tell you what is better for your story, but you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I understood your question: **Is there a right way to tell a story**, given that different authors might choose to tell the same story in entirely different ways?

In my opinion, the answer to this question is **no**.

**There's a large diversity in how we think and communicate**. One style might be perfect to a certain set of minds, but incompatible with another. Think of everyday life: Every once in a while, you meet somebody that you simply cannot communicate with. It's not that you dislike that person or that they are unfriendly per se, but simply that you can't seem to understand each other. He says "A", you understand "B", Babylonian confusion. A good example from my own experience is a good friend of mine who suffers from a mild form of autism. It took me a long time to figure out why we couldn't properly understand each other, and why, in general, he had so much trouble fitting into standard social situations. The reason is simply that he experiences the world a tiny bit different from me, and that we could not communicate with each other based on the standard that I apply to most of my other encounters.

Given this huge diversity in how we think and communicate, **it is up to you to choose your audience and adapt your style accordingly**. I know it sounds like a cliché -- but there's some truth to it. You will never reach everybody, and there's always going to be somebody who thinks your style is complete crap, *because tastes are different*. (I've heard there's even people out there who hate Harry Potter ...) So, it's up to you to define for whom you write. Once you have answered this question, you can decide which style is most appropriate for your audience, i.e. which way of writing will help yo to get your ideas across.

In my experience, my target audience is myself. I appreciate clarity and well-developed characters and am curious about what makes people tick. That's why I focus on exactly that: Character development, lean language, a clear storyline that doesn't distract from the complicated emotional responses of my characters.

And then there's Melville's Moby Dick. Many think this book a masterpiece, but I was nearly bored out of my mind. Why? Not because Moby Dick is a bad book per se, *but because Melville tells his story in a way that does not resonate with me*. I was intrigued by Starbucks and Ahab's insanity, but Melville did not deliver a character study about these two characters and hence lost me as an enthusiastic reader.

Hope I got the question right. ;-)

Comment: From a weirdo who actually loves *Moby Dick*: "choose your audience and adapt your style accordingly" this is, of course, one way of doing things. "tell your story the best possible way and let your audience build itself" is another. What you are suggesting is what Don Brown and James Patterson are doing: rewriting basically the same story over and over again and enjoying commercial success (kudos to that); this is also why I stopped reading them.

Comment: I think I get your point. "My way" is to write for an audience, "your way" is to write according to your own standards and let your audience find you. (Is that about right?) I think the problem here is my use of the word "audience". It implies that I write for commercial success, which is not the case. What I mean is that I try to think about how I can tell my story to a reader that has not spent years of his life developing it. How can I tell a scene or a development in a way that somebody else will understand it? And how can I stay, at the same time, true to my own ideals?

Comment: Not only writing for myself but genuinely thinking about how I can tell something that is important to me in a way that will be understood -- that's what I mean when I say "Adapt your style to your audience". Drastic example: Somebody considers suicide. How do you tell that? How do you make sure your audience understands where these thoughts are coming from? You know it, because you have written an entire biography about this character -- but you can't possibly info-dump all of this on your audience. You task is to find a way to tell this story that the audience can understand.

Comment: More or less. I define my writing goal as writing a story I *myself* find interesting to read. And, no, my prospect readers do not have to spend a lifetime developing the level of comprehension necessary to appreciate my revolutionary approach to stringing words into sentences; on the contrary, I strive to achieve a level of transparency in my writing, which has one purpose: to deliver the story in the clearest and accessible way.

Comment: Making readers understand why your character commits suicide has more to do with logic, than style. If you manage to describe their motivations in a clear enough way, it does not matter how purple your prose is; you can write 5000 haiku if you wish. What bothered me in your statement is that you seemingly preach that the writer should cater their work to reader's taste, and that is something I consider fundamentally wrong.

Comment: (It's too bad there's no personal messages here, because I would love to continue this discussion ...) Publicly, I'll just add: I avoid preaching. And I think that genuine creativity is at odds with the established taste of any audience. Plus, I do expect an audience to be open for new ideas. My argument was more directed at the basic concept of communication. Over and out.

Comment: I should have said "state" perhaps, instead of "preach"; apologies if I offended you.

Comment: Don't worry, you didn't. I'm aware that the wording of my statement was bound to create some opposition, even I felt uncomfortable with it, but couldn't think of a better way to phrase it. (I've also been spending a lot of time recently working on scientific publications and presentations, so there's a decent chance I mixed up the vocabularies that I use for scientific and fictional writing ...)